# Prevent scroll to top after rerender in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem with scroll to top after rerender component.
Is there any way to prevent this ? I dont want to scroll to top after any rerender just change the content.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way of doing it in React, but it should work.

As described in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) page, there is a way to get the amount of pixels the user scrolled and store them in a variable. Then use that value to programmatically change the amount of scrolled pixels after the rerender. This is for Javascript, but it should also work for React.

Simple Example:

```js
// Get the scroll pixels from the top of the page (Store this before rerender)
const scrollFromTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
// Update the scroll pixels from the top of the page with the stored int value (Do this after rerender)
document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollFromTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give your component a state,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrolled) {
      return; // no more scrolling
    }
    setScrolled(true);
    // TODO: scroll to top here
  }, [scrolled]);

  // ...
};

export default MyComponent;
```